# Nest - how to write a span near query with multiple clauses?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to use NEST to write a query as described in:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-span-near-query.html

I have a collection of values to use as a SpanTerm clause. The collection size varies by query.

If the collection size was limited I could do:

```
var sn = q.SpanNear(snr => snr.Clauses(c => c.SpanTerm(), c => c.SpanTerm(), ...))
```

How do I do it dynamically (unknown clauses count)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static class SpanNearQueryDescriptorExtensions 
{
    public static void SpanTermClauses<T>(this SpanNearQueryDescriptor<T> descriptor, Expression<Func<T, object>> field, string[] terms)
        where T : class
    {
        descriptor.Clauses(terms
            .Select(t => new Func<SpanQuery<T>, SpanQuery<T>>(query => query.SpanTerm(field, t)))
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var terms = new[] {"term1", "term2"};

client.Search<Docuemnt>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .SpanNear(sp => sp
            .Slop(12)
            .SpanTermClauses(f => f.Title, terms))));
```

Hope it helps.